# DJango 1.6 model.BinaryField causes TypeError

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've created a class model using DJango 1.6 with python 2.7 as follows:

```
class Company(models.Model):
        Name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        Email = models.EmailField
        CompanyLogo = models.BinaryField
```

trying to create the representing sql using `python manage.py sql fetch` resulted in error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    unbound method contribute_to_class() must be called with BinaryField instance as first argument (got ModelBase instance instead)
```

the corresponding field in the postgresql database is of type bytea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both `EmailField` and `BinaryField` are missing the `()` changing the class to be written like this solved the issue

```
class Company(models.Model):
        Name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        Email = models.EmailField()
        CompanyLogo = models.BinaryField()
```